# SwiftUI Error: "Cannot infer contextual base in reference to member 'decimalPad' "

Tags: swiftui

So I get the previous error and this one: "Value of type 'TextField' has no member 'keyboardType' " on the 24th line **.keyboardType(.decimalPad)**

I am following a tutorial, and other people have said that they've copied my code and it runs in their Xcode, but I don't know why it doesn't run on mine. There are 3 other files I could include (one for the ContentView, one for ExpenseItems, and one for Expenses), but this is the only one that gives those errors.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
import SwiftUI

@available(macOS 12.0, *)
struct AddView: View {
    @ObservedObject var expenses: Expenses
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss

    @State private var name = ""
    @State private var type = "Personal"
    @State private var amount = 0.0

    let types = ["Buisness", "Personal"]
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            Form {
                TextField("Name", text: $name)

                Picker("Type", selection: $type){
                ForEach(types, id:\.self){
                    Text($0)
                }
            }
            TextField("Amount", value: $amount, format: .currency(code: "USD"))
                .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
        }
        .navigationTitle("Add New Expense")
        .toolbar {
            Button("Save") {
                let item = ExpenseItem(name: name, type: type, amount: amount)
                expenses.items.append(item)
                dismiss()
            }
        }
    }
}
}
struct AddView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        if #available(macOS 12.0, *) {
            AddView(expenses: Expenses())
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `keyboardType` modifier (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/form/keyboardtype(_:)) is available for `iOS`, `iPadOS`, `Catalyst`, and `tvOS`. Given your `@available` tag, it looks like you're trying to run this on `macOS`, for which this modifier doesn't exist.

Comment: You are so right!  I didn't realize that this version of  Xcode gives you the option to change your platform when creating your project or when viewing your code

Comment: Great -- you can mark the answer as correct/accepted by clicking the green checkmark.